# Store Task in array and display result continously

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've create a task and store it in array to listen to multiple udp port. What I'm trying to achieve is display the result if it receive a message

```
 private void StartListening(int[] rcv_listofPorttoListen)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rcv_listofPorttoListen.Length; i++)
        {
            udpClients[i] = new UdpClient();
            udpClients[i].Client.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, rcv_listofPorttoListen[i]));
            iPEndPoints[i] = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
            Debug.Log("Port use is " + rcv_listofPorttoListen[i].ToString());
            task[i] = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    //var recvBuffer = udpClient.Receive(ref iPEndPoints[tasknumber]);
                    //Debug.Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvBuffer));

                    Debug.Log(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(udpClients[i].Receive(ref iPEndPoints[i])));

                }
            });
           //Display task value if it receive a message
        }
    }
```

Comment: So? What is your question exactly? Is something not working?

Comment: @frankhermes the broadcast message is not displaying if I store the task in the array what code I'm lacking or do I need to refactor my code